# Debugging Multiple Web Docker Containers in Visual Studio 2017+

Tags: debugging, docker, docker-compose, visual-studio-2017

I've got a solution that contains two dockerized web projects.  I've got my docker-compose file setup to deploy both of those projects.

Both of those projects are set (in their respective projects), to launch a browser when they are debugged.

When I hit F5 to debug, it consistently starts a web browser pointing at one of those two projects, but not the other.  Nor is the one that it's picking the one we'd generally prefer to have launched.  Is there a way to control how many and which projects launch browser windows when debugging a docker solution containing multiple containers?

Answer (score 1):

Like this document here:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1191288/Debug-multiple-NET-Core-projects-concurrently-runn

> [image]
>
> we can debug multiple projects at the same time in Visual Studio 17 running on docker container.

Comment: Your comment seems to say the opposite of the codeproject site. The site says you are able to debug both projects using the single docker-compose startup project, not multiple startup projects. I haven't tested this to know what's the case.